# Running compilation scripts only if the source file is more recent than the compiled program

Tags: bash, shell-script, timestamps

I am trying to do is create a bash script that will run another bash script to compile some programs only if the source has changed.  What I have so far is a way to get the timestamps for each file in seconds since J2000 epoch:

```
#get a list of the source timestamps
sourceTimes=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%s" *.f)

#get a list of the program timestamps
exeTimes=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%s")
```

and an install script

```
./make_common_lib.bsh build
./make_common_lib.bsh install
```

I want to figure out how to create an if state such that (in semi-pseudocode)

```
if [any of $sourceTimes>$exeTimes];
then  #run make_common_lib.bsh script
else  #Do nothing
fi
```

My best guess so far is to somehow use `read` but I am not sure how I could index both variables at the same time.

If there is a really easy way to do this I apologize as I am very new to bash scripting, but so far none of my google searches have really returned anything useful.

Some more information:

The timestamp variables are in a format like

```
1432326068 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326069 1432326068 1432326069 1432326069
```

Comment: Why not use `make`? It is explicitly designed to handle this requirement.

Comment: I do realize this but I'm actually working with someone else's program and for some reason they didn't use make.  The problem with make (I think) is that I would need to write out each dependency and there are more than 100 in the common libraries alone (and there's an entire other group of files that I would have to do the same thing for).

Comment: That's what wildcards are for.

Comment: @Andrew What people usually do is to automatically generate the list of dependencies (usually you run `make depend` or `make dep` to regenerate the list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your Build Script Method**

If you want to keep to the "bash build method", then you are probably best off "touching" a file (`touch lastbuild`) when the build script is ran and completes the build. In addition the build script could then look for the file generated by touch (if it doesn't exist, assume a build is needed), or if it exists use `find` to see if any newer files exist:

```
find . -name "*.[ch]" -newer lastbuild
```

and then build if that output is 1 or more lines (could be checked with something like `wc -l`).

**Using Make instead**

This is best managed by something like a Makefile (specifically used to do this kind of dependency checking).

```
default: all

all: dependency1.o dependency2.o

dependency1.o: dependency1.c
    ./make_common_lib.bsh build

dependency2.o: dependency2.c
    ./make_common_lib.bsh build

install: 
    ./make_common_lib.bsh install
```

Creating a dummy "build" script:

```
$ cat make_common_lib.bsh 
#! /bin/sh

echo "Build $1"
```

We can now run make:

```
$ make
./make_common_lib.bsh build
Build build
./make_common_lib.bsh build
Build build
```

You could also replace the `./make_common_lib.bsh build` with the command that `./make_common_lib.bsh build` would issue to build `dependency1.o` etc:

```
dependency1.o: dependency1.c
    gcc -c dependency1.c
```

Makefiles also allow for symbol substitution, so you could declare the complier and compiler flags earlier in the Makefile:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall
```

and then make references to them in your rules:

```
dependency1.o: dependency1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c dependency1.c
```

**Note that the line that is indented after a dependency declaration must start with a tab and not spaces.**

**Shortening dependency rules list**

The OP asked if it's possible to do shorter ways of declaring all dependencies. It is possible with a few tricks using GNU's make (note not all these will work with vanilla make).

You can do variable substitution. Given the declaration:

```
SRCS=dependency1.c dependency2.c dependency3.c
```

You can then create an objects rule using variable substitution:

```
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

this will replace all `.c`'s with `.o`'s. In effect giving a line of the form:

```
OBJS=dependency1.o dependency2.o dependency3.o
```

You can then further do a shortening of the "compile command" using the special variables `$<` and `$@`:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<  -o $@
```

`$<` represents the prerequisite in GNU make parlance (or dependency as I've called it) and `$@` the target, and so it will end up issuing:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -O2 -c dependency1.c  -o dependency1.o
/usr/bin/gcc -Wall -O2 -c dependency2.c  -o dependency2.o
.
.
.
```

Putting this all together, with linking options and a command to link and compile the executable `$(TARGET)`:

```
# Globals
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
LIBS=-ldependencylib

# declare all the sources
SRCS=dependency1.c dependency2.c

# declare the objects files using variable substitution (find .c and replace with .o)
OBJS=$(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Target executable name:
TARGET=myexefile

default: all

all: $(TARGET)
    @echo Target has been built

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<  -o $@

install:
    ./make_common_lib.bsh install
```

Note that there are many things you can do with GNU make, and it is well documented here [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: thanks for the response.  I wish that the people who originally designed this software had done a straight up make file but they haven't.  One question I have is, is there someway to do this without having to write out each dependency?  There are over 100 separate files that need to be checked and I don't really want to have to write out a dependency for each one.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use some GNU make shortcuts to handle multiple dependencies.